# Local site redirect to wrong address

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, magento, redirect

So i have Ubuntu 16.04 with apache2 installed on it, and my local sites are inside if /var/www/html/ directory.

The problem is that one of my sites based on magento 1.9 redirect me to wrong url everytime. Whenever i'm trying to access **localhost/my-site/** it redirects me to **localhost/my-site/localhost/my-site/** instead.

I have tried to change .htaccess and even deleting it from site root folder same as changing apache2 hosts configurations inside of apache2/site-available folder and even creating new virtual host in that folder but that didn't helped.

I also tried to fully reinstall apache but no result. My **hosts** file has just localhost defined now so it can not be conflict with other host.

I think that it replace index.php url part with localhost/my-site but i have no idea how to fix it.

I would realy appreciate some help becose i'm trying to fix this few day already with no result.

Thanks.

Comment: Check the settings in the Magento admin under: *system > configuration > general > web > Unsecure|Secure > Base URL* - in your case it should probably be *http(s)://localhost/my-site/*

Comment: I did already and tried different setting there - nothink helps.
Btw admin pannel doesnt work too so i have to change that in database.

Comment: If you've updated your database. Delete the contents of the `/var/cache/` folder. Sometimes even after the base URL has been updated the cache will maintain the redirect. You'll also want to clear your browser cache since they cache 301 redirects as well.

Comment: I have pulled site from git so var and media folders was in gitignore. I've created it later empty so it cannot be a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I have solved this problem, by deleting cache folder on my local pc in /var/tmp directory. Apparently this cache was saved when i got redirect first time and after that i was redirecter becose of this.

Hope this will help someone.